# How to populate a multi-dimensional associative array item with variables?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to populate a multi-dimensional associative array item in PHP with the following variables:

```
$number = 1;
$status = 'active';
```

My array item is currently 'hard-coded' like this:

```
$settings['1']['active'];
```

How can I replace the `'1'` and `'active'` with `$number` and `$status`?

I've tried the following but am not sure if it is the right way to do it:

```
$settings['$number']['$status'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interpolate values in strings defined with  single  quotes, you should use double `"`:

```
$settings["$number"]["$status"];
```

*or*

```
$settings["{$number}"]["{$status}"];
```

In your case they are not necessary at all :

```
 $settings[$number][$status];
```

Answer (score 0):

Close!
Try:

```
$settings[$number][$status];
```

(**Note:** When you start indexing arrays with variables, it would be good to first check that the element exists in the array with **array_key_exists()**
https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: Won't that result in `$settings[1][active];`? I thought I'd need `'`s for an associative array i.e. `$settings['1']['active'];`

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't actually have indexes for arrays, so `$settings[1]` and `$settings['1']` will function the same way. If you'd like to read more about it, check out this [PHP.net page on arrays](https://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.array.php).